# Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature failed when running Prerequisites.ps1

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

While installing Sitecore 9.1, I'm getting an error when I run Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path C:\resourceFiles\Prerequisites.json

I ran Update-Module SitecoreInstallFramework before installing to make sure my SIF was up to date.

I'm not sure how to troubleshoot or what might be causing this. Any suggestions?

```
[---------------------------------------- WindowsFeatures : EnableWindowsOptionalFeature ---------------------------]
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature failed. Error code = 0x800f0954
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration -Path C:\resourceFiles\Prerequisites.js ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:00:43
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature : Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature failed. Error code = 0x800f0954
At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.0.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:641 char:25
+                         & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Dism.Commands.EnableWindowsOptionalFeatureCommand
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May have something to do with your domain / WSUS?

Try setting the following using gpedit.msc:

Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Specify settings for optional component installation and component repair

Check the “Download repair content and optional features directly from Windows Uodate”

There’s also a registry key that does something similar. Was the solution on my end. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!  I followed these instructions and ran the command again.  SIF stopped for a very long time where it used to be erroring out.  I minimized and forgot about it.  About an hour later, it kicked back into gear and started installing the prerequisites as expected, and it completed successfully.

Comment: To get this feature activated through regedit navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` > `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Servicing`  and create the key `RepairContentServerSource` with a value of `2` as a true value

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to start

1. You could google error code (`0x800f0954`) and see whether you can solve it on your machine (if the problem is the same as yours - most of the results are related to **.NET 3.5** installation. I am not sure if **Prerequisites.js** has it on the list)
2. You could figure out which feature causes the problems on your machine and then search for a solution online.

comment/remove all features in `FeatureName` table in **Prerequisites.js** and then enable one and run the installation. Repeat with each feature until you find problematic one.

```
    "WindowsFeatures": {
    "Type": "EnableWindowsOptionalFeature",
    "Params": {
        "Online": true,
        "FeatureName": [
            "IIS-WebServer",
            "IIS-WebServerManagementTools",
            "IIS-ASPNET",
            "IIS-ASPNET45",
            "NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45",
            "WAS-NetFxEnvironment",
            "WAS-ProcessModel",
            "WAS-WindowsActivationService"
        ],
        "All": true
    }
}
```

3. You could install everything manually.

You will find a section for that in the installation guide: **2.4.2 Manual Installation of the Prerequisites**

4. I will share this but please read before you copy/paste/execute

A long time ago, at the beginning of **SIF** thing, I created a script for installing prerequisites by myself on a completely new machine without anything installed. I am not sure if this gonna work but if this will help you with prerequisites installation maybe it's worth to try.

[**WebPI.PS**](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WebPI.PS/1.0.1/Content/WebPI.PS.psd1) - this is written by me. You can find it in [powershellgallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WebPI.PS/1.0.1/Content/WebPI.PS.psd1) and check source code [here](https://github.com/PowerShellLibrary/WebPI.PS) if you don't trust unknown modules.

Last time I tested in on a new machine was more than 1 year ago.

**Use script at your own risk.**

```
## Define parameters #########
$SqlServer = "."
$SqlAdminUser = "admin"
$SqlAdminPassword = "b"
##############################

Dism.exe /online /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:NetFx3
Dism.exe /online /Enable-Feature /all /FeatureName:IIS-ASPNET

Install-Module WebPI.PS
Import-Module WebPI.PS

Invoke-WebPI  /Install "/Products:UrlRewrite2,WDeploy36,DACFX,SQLDOM"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlServer -Username $SqlAdminUser -Password $SqlAdminPassword -Query "USE [master]"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlServer -Username $SqlAdminUser -Password $SqlAdminPassword -Query "sp_configure 'contained database authentication',1"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SqlServer -Username $SqlAdminUser -Password $SqlAdminPassword -Query "RECONFIGURE;"
```